# How to let users only be able to give permissions with 'contribute' as the highest level? SP 2007

Tags: 2007, permissions

I have to give a few users the ability to give permissions however I would like to limit their ability to only give permissions as high as "Contribute".
They cannot have the ability to grant, Approve, Manage Hierarchy, Design and of course Full Control.

How can I create a group/user that is limited to grant permissions only to the level of 'contribute'?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately there is no way to differentiate `Manage Permissions` (until SharePoint 2013 where you can add a SPSecurityEventReceiver).
If you give someone `Manage Permissions` then they can add all kinds of permissions.

But instead of giving these users the `Manage Permissions` permissions you can:

1. Create a SharePoint group for each of the types of permissions the users should be able to add people to.
2. Grant that group the appropriate permissions
3. Make the users owners of that group

Comment: Hello and thank you, but if there are a dozen subsites ( for each company section ) that would mean a dozen "read", a dozen "contribute"..etc would that be right??